# Connecting to a SonicWall VPN from a Linux machine

Tags: linux, vpn

Is there a SonicWall client for Linux? When I searched around I could only find answers several years old.

Comment: I found a knowledge base page on their site that explains how to install the VPN client for linux. https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw5918. Not sure if this can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no special client for SonicWall. Use Openswan on your linux box, configure a tunnel between your box and sonicwall, with NAT traversal.  Here are few docs:

<s>http://www.vpn-technology.com/Interoperability/SonicWALL%20VPN%20with%20Red%20Hat%20Linux.pdf</s>

http://www.sonicwall.com/us/support/2134_8175.html

http://archives.free.net.ph/message/20070322.043752.86474680.en.html

Edit: follow the comments for better answer

Comment: That's no longer true, FYI, there is now a Sonicwall connection utility for Linux

Comment: @JustinBuser Details?

Comment: NetExtender is the Sonicwall VPN client for desktops (as opposed to an always-on connection, to a satelite office for example).  The client does have Linux builds available and works fairly well.  If you have the SonicWall Virtual Office enabled on your appliance then you can download the client by going to `https://your-sonicwall-public-ip:4433` and logging in with a regular (not "admin") user account. I'm not certain those details are all stock settings, but we've used them a few times on a TZ205 appliance with ~5.8.0+ firmware.

Comment: ps) the latest version of NetExtender can also be downloaded after logging in to `http://mysonicwall.com` - again YMMV depending on what you own and have registered to your account

Comment: All three URLs are now dead links.

Answer (score 12):

The download link for the Linux client from *SonicWall* is [here](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/cgi-bin/welcome).

Go to that page, the follow the directions to log in to the Beta site as a guest (username is "demo", password is "password" - as provided on the page), then click the large *NetExtender* button, which will initiate a download of the latest *.tgz* file.

Extract it and run `./install` as root (using `sudo`), then run the GUI. The installer has instructions to help you all along the way.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes do not ask questions in the comments. If you cannot find the answer in another question, then use the Ask Question button at the top of the page to ask your own question and get your own answers.

Answer (score 7):

As it was remarked that most links in the existing answers were dead and
not much information was available,
I thought to list below some resources that still exist:

The NetExtender clients (and others) can be downloaded from the
[Clients Download page](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/cgi-bin/clientdownloads)
and installation notes are available in this
[Knowledge Base article](https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170503561905844). Here are the links from the above page:

- [Linux 32-bits](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/NetExtender.tgz)
- [Linux 64-bits](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/NetExtender.x86_64.tgz)
- [Windows .exe](https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/NXSetupU.exe)

Some more useful articles :

- [Ubuntu Linux: How to setup a VPN connection to a SonicWall router using Openswan and Pre-shared Keys (PSK)](https://www.myintervals.com/blog/2009/05/18/ubuntu-linux-how-to-setup-a-vpn-connection-to-a-sonicwall-router-using-openswan-and-pre-shared-keys-psk/) (from 2009)
- [How to Install Dell’s SSL VPN client – NetExtender – on Ubuntu 16.04.x](https://thangamaniarun.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/how-to-install-dells-ssl-vpn-client-netextender-on-ubuntu-16-04-x/) (from 2016)
- [SonicWALL VPN with FreeS/WAN using IKE](https://www.scribd.com/document/2088756/SonicWALL-VPN-With-Red-Hat-Linux) (old one from 2002)

Comment: Thank you! NetExtender works for me. It's closed source, it has ugly Java GUI, it causes tons of SELinux warnings, but it gets the job done. The open source solutions ask for ID and shared secret, and I don't have them. NetExtender doesn't even ask for them. The ID is probably GroupVPN, but the shared secret eludes me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is model specific but where I work we have an Aventail WorkPlace SonicWall VPN. When you put the hostname that you use to connect to it into a browser it takes you to a page that has links where you can download client software to connect to the VPN box. From here there are links to down Linux VPN client software.

The software comes in 32/64 bit formats as tarballs named, AventailConnect-Linux.tar & AventailConnect-Linux64.tar.

The only other branding that I've noticed on the download page is that it says nortel in the title page, and "Aventail Connect with smarttunneling", on the side of the download page.

I wrote up on my blog about this as well, http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/4720/setting-up-aventail-vpn-software-on-linux-fedoracentosrhel/. I included some screenshots in that post of the various pages where you can download the Aventail VPN client software.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a My Sonicwall account, you can download SSL VPN clients for Linux. The Program is called NetExtender.

Answer (score 0):

Note that NetExtender is a gui app intended to run from a desktop session. If you want something that'll run at system level, you'll have to go for OpenSwan or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Download netextender from sonic wall. Add the suffix :4433 to the IP address and specify the domain as LocalDomain. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is still useful.
Where I work Connect Tunnel is used, try the connection with NetExtender without success, thanks to this answer browse the demos until you find a link where the installer that was mentioned in other pages "ConnectTunnel-Linux64.tar" is downloaded https://access.sma-demo.com/workplace/access/home there will download a .jar, unzip and follow the steps https://www.dundee.ac.uk/guides/vpn-linux.
translated by Google

Por si aun es util.
en donde trabajo se usa "Connect Tunnel", intente la conexión con "NetExtender" sin éxito, gracias a esta respuesta navegue por los demos hasta encontrar un link donde se descarga el instalador que se mencionaban en otras paginas "ConnectTunnel-Linux64.tar" https://access.sma-demo.com/workplace/access/home alli descargaran un .jar, se descomprime y se siguen los pasos https://www.dundee.ac.uk/guides/vpn-linux.