# Windows + VPN + port forward or proxy

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vpn, proxy

I have two computers on LAN:

- 192.168.0.2 (windows 7 workstation)
- 192.168.0.3 (debian linux server)

My windows 7 workstation (.0.2) is connected to external VPN and has also IP 10.0.15.5 and can connect to SQL server at 10.0.15.2 port 1433 ...

I also want to connect from my debian linux server (.0.3) to the same SQL database. Unfortunately I am not able to make a VPN connection from linux server because VPN is windows-only.

So I was wondering if I could somehow make a port forward or proxy or tunnel or whatever that would allow me to connect from linux box to DB server over windows workstation's VPN..

e.g.:
192.168.0.3 (linux) -> 192.168.0.2, port 8888 (or whatever) -> 10.0.15.2, port 1433

Comment: What VPN technology is being used - SSTP?

Comment: Don't know but on windows I use "Sonicwall Global VPN Client" and everything I got from sysadmin of the VPN was IP address and preshared key.

Comment: I also tried to connect from my linux box following the tutorial at http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2009/05/18/ubuntu-linux-how-to-setup-a-vpn-connection-to-a-sonicwall-router-using-openswan-and-pre-shared-keys-psk/  but it won't work (003 "sonicwall" #1: Informational Exchange message must be encrypted)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/141834/connecting-to-a-sonicwall-vpn-from-a-linux-machine) ?

Comment: yes I did but couldn't make it work.. It works without problems as Windows client but not on Linux - but I need a connection to the database from Linux