# Are VPN clients interchangeable?

Tags: networking, vpn

Is there any reason that I cant connect to a VPN using any client (eg openconnect)? My work wants me to use SonicWall (which doesnt seem to support linux). Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: VPN clients aren't interchangeable.  Generally, you need the client from the same vendor as the VPN server.  I am not aware of any other VPN clients that connect to a Sonicwall device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your work also gets to set the rules. If they require you to use something besides Linux, you really don't get a say in the matter.*

VPN is not a specific, defined protocol; it is a category of service and there are many different protocols that may be utilized to provide this service. For this reason, one VPN tunneling utility has a very low chance of connecting with a different VPN service.

That said, NetExtender is the Sonicwall tunnel utility, and sources report there is a Linux client available (see comments below accepted answer here: [Connecting to a SonicWall VPN from a Linux machine](https://superuser.com/questions/141834/connecting-to-a-sonicwall-vpn-from-a-linux-machine)).

See also the Sonicwall NetExtender Linux documentation: https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/180105195559153